# Docker: Couldn't connect to docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket -is it running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a somewhat peculiar scenario. I tend to execute command `docker-compose -f dev.yml up --build` to get the containers up and work. Here, `dev.yml` is development version of `docker-compose.yml`. Till this very morning every thing was working fine, and all of the sudden, I started getting error regarding failure to connect to docker-daemon.

Now, this problem only occurs when I have `--build` included in the command. If I only execute `docker-compose -f dev.yml up` it works fine. If I include `--build` into the command and execute it using `sudo` it works fine again.

**Things verified:**

- User executing the command is added to docker group which has
  permissions for `/var/run/docker.sock`

**Details of dev.yml**

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data_dev: {}
  postgres_backup_dev: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup_dev:/backups
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=rocky


  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=rocky
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /tmp/
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
    expose:
      - "8000"
    env_file:
      - ./dev.env


  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/nginx/development/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
    links:
      - django
    volumes_from:
      - django


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis


  celeryworker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    env_file: ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
      - postgres
    volumes_from:
      - django
    command: celery -A rocky.taskapp worker -l INFO
    restart: on-failure


  celerybeat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/development/Dockerfile
    env_file: ./dev.env
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis
      - postgres
      - celeryworker
    volumes_from:
      - django
    command: celery -A rocky.taskapp beat -l INFO
```

**Update:**
My colleague got stuck with same issue. I have my doubts on config for celerybeat, celeryworker. Can anyone please verify? Thanks.

Comment: you find a solution?   the `docker` command works fine for me, but `docker-compose` fails.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For me the following command worked,

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER -R .
```

Check this conversation I had on github, [Issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4970)

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours, adding myself to the docker group, reinstalling docker, launching docker-compose with sudo wasn't an option... This finally did it!

Comment: I myself struggled with it for long time before finding it out. Glad it helped.

Comment: OMG, I can finally stop pulling my hair out. Sounds like this is common after docker updates?

Comment: I agree with this answer but be careful if you are some other folder in current folder, for example docker volume, in my case, I have website and database volume… which require *www-data* or other, not $USER. So chown $USER: only files/folder required to build an run containers

Answer (score 14):

I just included `sudo` before `docker-compose`, and that did it.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this issue after a fresh install of `docker` and `docker-compose` on Ubuntu, trying to run `docker-compose up`. I managed to solve it [as described here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1214#issuecomment-239021745) by adding my user to the `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER}
```

and logging out and back in.

You may be able to avoid having to log out and back in [as described here](https://superuser.com/a/354475/161365) by running

```
su - $USER
```

Comment: It was never about user. The problem was a corrupt tar ball generated. You can take a look at the answer I have given. It has a link to discussion on github with one of the guys from docker contributors.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I understand. However, I ran into the exact same error as described in the title and this was the solution. It may help others, so I added it as an answer, but you should certainly _accept_ the answer that solved your particular problem.

Comment: Oh yes definitely, I was not trying to discard your answer. I just thought you might have missed something while reading up that big piece of question :P

Comment: I am all in for help, because for this things like this there are no single solutions.

Comment: That solved it for me. Running the su command allowed me to not log out and in again.

Answer (score 4):

This is most like a permissions issue and docker-compose is giving entirely the wrong error.

Try building the images by hand with `docker` instead of `docker-compose`, e.g. 

    `docker build -f=./compose/django/development/Dockerfile .`

 and likely you will see what the real issue is.

Answer (score 4):

Use `$ sudo service docker start` or `$ sudo systemctl start docker` to start the docker daemon back again if it was stopped somehow.

Also you may have to add your user to the docker group, eg. using `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`. This requires opening a new shell to take effect!

Answer (score 1):

So maybe running with `sudo` can fix your problem but you should ensure that your user can access to Docker engine with the current privileges without sudo. Solution is so simple.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Its dumb, but in my case, in docker-compose.yml  I kept uppercase name for image and was getting that error. I checked my docker logs and finally fixed that name to lowercase.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting docker service fixed the problem for me.

```
$ systemctl restart docker.service
```